# Calculate Cumulative Sum in Same Cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to calculate total stock quantity of each item separately.
I have last column name "Total Stock Quantity" in which I want sum separately.

Condition: Whenever I give new quantity to the item, it should get added/subtract to same cell "Total Stock Quantity".

I have attached screen shot for example.

Here initially "Total Stock Quantity" is 0 and I am adding an item (quantity=15) to list:
[image: Here initially "Total Stock Quantity" is 0 and I am adding an item (quantity=15) to list]

Now "Total Stock Quantity" should be 15
[image: Now "Total Stock Quantity" should be 15]

Now I am giving new quantity for that item (quantity=10)
[image: Now I am giving new quantity for that item (quantity=10)]

Now the "Total Stock Quantity" should be 25 which is Previous Value (15) + New Value (10)
[image: Now the "Total Stock Quantity" should be 25 which is Previous Value (15) + New Value (10)]

Basically, it should get updated every time I enter new stock unit for my item

So, what should I do to make Cumulative sum for the same cell.

Please Provide me a solution for this :)

Comment: Please provide what you have tried. Then we can help you to fix or improve it. This is no free code writing service. Also you need to ask a proper question ([ask]). If you have done nothing yet check out how to use the `Worksheet_Change` event and come back with an attempt.

Comment: Should this be for only a **single** cell or for a **column** of cells ???

Comment: Use a `worksheet_change` event macro to determine when you should add to the **Total** cell. Be aware that this method will eliminate the ability to track your changes; troubleshoot data entry errors, etc.  A better method might be to have a worksheet for a history of transactions, and then display this (your table as shown in your question) on a summary sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is an example that does what you described as you need.
For your workbook/project, **please consider the warnings in Ron Rosenfeld's comment**.

Changes in the cell "E2" is the trigger to a macro that do the sum and update the other cell value. In this example, it'll sum the value added in the cell "E2" to the value in cell "G2". It'll have to be updated given your needs.
[image: Example of Excel Sheet]

[image: The code as Worksheet Change]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$E$2" Then
        Call Update_TsQ
    End If
End Sub

Sub Update_TsQ()

Dim QiS As Long
Dim TsQ As Long

QiS = Range("E2").Value
TsQ = Range("G2").Value

TsQ = TsQ + QiS
Range("G2").Value = TsQ

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to disable events `Application.EnableEvents = False` if you change a cell value inside the `Worksheet_Change` event otherwise this will trigger another change event and you could get stuck in a loop. • Make sure you have a proper error handling so you never end up with events disabled and they get enabled again in the end of the change event (or in case of an error).